# P value of intercept

Tags: linear-regression

I was working on linear regression example. I have generated output using Data Analysis tool pack of Excel. Now I want to know how to calculate P value of intercept in linear regression output using formula in excel?

Comment: Use the [LINEST](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) function

Comment: I have to calculated P value using TDist() function in excel?

Comment: yes, for simple linear regression use the Student distribution ([TDIST](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TDIST-function-630a7695-4021-4853-9468-4a1f9dcdd192)). [See details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption)

Comment: Note that in many cases LINEST is more convenient than Analysis tool pack. LINEST is recalculated in real time when source data is changed. Also, it can calculate the standard deviations and degrees of freedom for the estimated values.

Comment: But this function does not give P value for intercept? is there any formula to find P value for intercept?

Comment: LINEST calculates, among other values, the intercept, its standard deviation and the number of degrees of freedom. Refer to Excel help (see my link above) to find what is where. Then, calculate the P-value from these values using the TDIST function. Refer to Wikipedia (see my other link above) for the exact formula.

Comment: what are d.f. for intercept in TDIST()? When I used df=1, it give me error.

Comment: The estimates have the Student's distribution with n-k degrees of freedom. I believe you should have a textbook containing all this information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally I got answer.